# Different forms corresponding to “it”

Tags: grammar, gender, pronoun

I came across the sentence:

> **Der** Vorschlag ist gut, ich unterstütze **ihn**.

from a page at [Linguee](http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/search?source=auto&query=ihn).

Now, will the word *ihn* be the same form if we are referring to a *die* or *das* word?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The pronoun needs to agree with the gender (and the number) of the word it refers to:

> **Die** Idee ist gut, ich unterstütze **sie**.
>   **Das** Vorhaben ist gut, ich unterstütze **es**.
>   **Die** Vorschläge/Ideen/Vorhaben sind gut, ich unterstütze **sie**.

Comment: @Crissov: I’m not sure the bolding is helpful. It emphasizes the pronouns when what is actually changing is the (invisible) gender of the noun.

Comment: Yes, nominal gender (+ case) is usually invisible in the noun itself, but visible in the articles, pronouns and adjectives that have to agree with it. I highlighted both the accompanying attributes on the left and the anaphoric references on the right. With feminine, neuter and plural their morphologic relation is easy to spot, but with masculine as in the question it’s not, because only there the accusative, which is the case required by _unterstützen_, has a form separate from the nominative (and in personal pronouns even the stem changes). I guess that part would be a truly helpful answer.

Answer (score 2):

The word *ihn* is the masculine direct object form of "it". Neuter and feminine "it" forms do not change when they are the direct object though.

Answer (score 1):

English language has completely lost grammatical genders of nouns over the centuries. Only in personal pronouns rudimentary rests of the previous Indo-European gender system survived, and together with this reduction to almost nothing also the rules changed:

In English the grammatical gender of pronouns is very strongly bound to the biological sexus. In English you refer to a male person always with masculine gender (*"he"*), and for female persons you always use a feminine gender (*"she"*). For things that are not persons, you use always neuter gender (*"it"*). (With some exceptions: pets, ships, etc.)

But German has kept the old Indo-European gender system, like most of the other languages that developed from this root (Spanisch, Hindi, Russian, French, etc.). Every noun has an individual grammatical gender.

Some examples:

- The german word for *spoon* (der Löffel) is masculine, so you have to use a masculine pronoun when you refer to ***him***(!).
- The german word for *fork* (die Gabel) is feminine, so when you talk about ***her*** you have to use a feminine pronoun.
- The german word for *knife* (das Messer) is neuter, so here you have to use the same grammatical gender as in English for the pronoun when you talk about ***it***.

Note also: The German word for *girl* (das Mädchen) is neuter (because *Mädchen* is a diminutive and all diminutives are always neuter), so when you talk about ***it*** you should use the neuter pronoun. Same for *"das Weib"* (crone, hag, vixen). This is the old word for a woman, but now has a pejorative connotation. But when you use this word for a lady you don't like, you have to refer to ***it*** with a neuter pronoun.
Fun fact: The german word for *female/feminine* is *»weiblich«*, but it is derived form *»das Weib«* which is a neuter noun (but is used for female persons).

The German word for *child* (das Kind) is neuter. So in german you can talk about a certain child without mentioning ***its*** biological sexus.

But since about 20 or 30 years there is coming up an exception for pronouns that refer to persons. When you refer to persons, you are allowed to use the grammatical gender for the pronoun that matches with the biologicals sexus. This allows you to refer to a *Mädchen* (girl) with a feminine pronoun. But this is a relatively young exception in German language, and older people still are not aware of its existence, sou you still often will hear ***it*** when someone is talking about a girl.

Also note, that the gender is a grammatical feature, that depends on the word only. It does not depend on the thing that is named with this word. If you have different nouns that can mean the same physical object, those names can have different grammatical genders: "Das Auto" (*es/it*), "der Wagen" (*er/he*) and "die Karre" (*sie/she*) can mean the very same shabby old limousine. But which gender you have to use to refer to this car depends on the noun that you use for it. It does not depend on the physical object.